# Issues with System Linq between SDK 2.0.2 and 2.1.2

Tags: .net, .net-core

If I update my `global.json` to use SDK 2.1.2 (or 2.1.3) from 2.0.2, I get build errors relating to not being able to find System.Linq

> error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Linq' does not exist in the namespace 'System' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

What do I need to do to fix this? I can't find any documentation on this.

I'm referencing `System.Linq` (v4.1.0 or 4.3.0) directly

Comment: Can you share an example project that reproduces this error?